# Error building adapters on new macbook

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Facing this issue when running

```
mfpdev adapter build all
```

> WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 45, column 21
>   [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
>   com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at
>   com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:jar:8.0.2017021701 ->
>   javax.xml:jaxp-api:jar:1.4.2 @  [ERROR] Unknown packaging: adapter @
>   line 12, column 16  @  [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project ->
>   [Help 1] [ERROR]    [ERROR]   The project
>   my.com.ge:loginAdapter:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   (/Users/clheng/MPOS/mpos_gelm_fo_mfp8_adapters/loginAdapter/pom.xml)
>   has 2 errors [ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
>   com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at
>   com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:jar:8.0.2017021701 ->
>   javax.xml:jaxp-api:jar:1.4.2: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   javax.xml:jaxp-api:jar:1.4.2: Could not transfer artifact
>   javax.xml:jaxp-api:pom:1.4.2 from/to remote-repos
>   (http://ec2-54-254-246-162.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/artifactory/remote-repos):
>   Access denied to:
>   http://ec2-54-254-246-162.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/artifactory/remote-repos/javax/xml/jaxp-api/1.4.2/jaxp-api-1.4.2.pom,
>   ReasonPhrase: Forbidden. -> [Help 2] [ERROR]     Unknown packaging:
>   adapter @ line 12, column 16 [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack
>   trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run
>   Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
>   [ERROR] [Help 2]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
>
> Error building adapter loginAdapter.  See the preceding messages for
>   details.

Comment: Does it work if you build adapter one at a time?

Comment: Nope. Found the issue. It was cause by the maven setup previously. Thx for you kind help Vivin

Comment: You should add what the issue was and how you fixed it as an answer , so that it will help someone else in future

Comment: Yes sure Vivin. This was a mistake when setting up maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a shared Macbook, previous setting in .m2 folder which will download other files from the link above. Removing it solved the issue.

A new fresh installation of maven on a macbook will not enounter this issue. Thanks.